# Does SQL Server automatically update the foreign key relationships between tables when one of those tables is renamed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key, table

What happens to the foreign key relationships on a table if that table is renamed?

Comment: You can probably test that at: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Renaming a table does not change the underlying object_id for that table.  Foreign Key relationships are tracked using object_id's.

Take a look at the information in `select * from sys.foreign_keys`.

Assuming the following parent/child tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[QueueDatabase];
DROP TABLE if exists [dbo].[Queue];

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Queue](
    [QueueID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SchemaName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [ObjectName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [Parameters] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [QueueStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [SessionID] [smallint] NULL,
    [RequestID] [int] NULL,
    [RequestStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Queue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QueueID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QueueDatabase](
    [QueueID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseOrder] [int] NULL,
    [DatabaseStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [DatabaseEndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [SessionID] [smallint] NULL,
    [RequestID] [int] NULL,
    [RequestStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QueueDatabase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QueueID] ASC,
    [DatabaseName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QueueDatabase]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QueueDatabase_Queue] FOREIGN KEY([QueueID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Queue] ([QueueID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QueueDatabase] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_QueueDatabase_Queue]
GO
```

---

Now, begin a transaction.  Select object_id's and object_names before and after executing sp_rename.  The object_names change, but the underlying object_id's remain the same.

```
begin transaction
--select object_id's and names before table rename
SELECT parent_object_id AS child_table_id
    ,object_name(parent_object_id) AS child_table
    ,referenced_object_id AS parent_table_id
    ,object_name(referenced_object_id) AS parent_table
FROM sys.foreign_keys

--rename the table
exec sp_rename 'dbo.queuedatabase','newqueuedatabase'

--select object_id's and names after table rename
SELECT parent_object_id AS child_table_id
    ,object_name(parent_object_id) AS child_table
    ,referenced_object_id AS parent_table_id
    ,object_name(referenced_object_id) AS parent_table
FROM sys.foreign_keys

--rollback
```

--before

```
| child_table_id | child_table   | parent_table_id | parent_table |
|----------------|---------------|-----------------|--------------|
| 1100687119     | QueueDatabase | 1068687005      | Queue        |
```

--after

```
| child_table_id | child_table      | parent_table_id | parent_table |
|----------------|------------------|-----------------|--------------|
| 1100687119     | newqueuedatabase | 1068687005      | Queue        |
```

---

Additionally, it should be noted that nothing magical happens to the `name` of the foreign key (assuming you used table names as part of the foreign key name)

Selecting from `sys.foreign_keys` reveals that the name remains the same even though it's now a little confusing since there is no table called QueueDatabase after the rename.

```
FK_QueueDatabase_Queue
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have `tableA` with columns `AID, AName`  and `tableB` with columns `BID, BName, AID` and `tableB.AID` references `tableA.AID`.

If I rename `tableA` to `zTableA`, the foreign key definition for `tableB.AID` is updated so that it references `zTableA` rather than `TableA`

This behaviour can be seen in management studio by scripting the foreign key before and after the table rename